# Display Product Categories based on Tags of a Product Woocommerce/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently im using this category display code

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'number' => 100,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false
);
$product_categories = get_terms('product_cat', $args);
$count = count($product_categories);
if ($count > 0) {
foreach($product_categories as $product_category) {
$cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($product_category - > term_id,'thumbnail_id', true);
$cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($cat_thumb_id);
$term_link = get_term_link($product_category, 'product_cat');
echo '<a href="'.$term_link.'"><img src="'.$cat_thumb_url.'"/></a>';
echo '<h4><a href="'.get_term_link($product_category).'">'.$product_category - > name.'</a></h4>';
}
}
?>
```

but i want to evolve this code to display product categories based on product tags is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Playing with my code i got what i want to display. BTW

> $str

stands for the product tag that you want to display

```
<?php                                             
  $args = array(
    'number'     => 100,
      'orderby'    => 'title',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false); 
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
if ( $count > 0 ){
foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
$args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'tax_query' => array(
         'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
             'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => 'white-wines'
'terms' => $product_category - > slug
),
array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
'field' => 'slug',
// 'terms' => 'white-wines'
'terms' => array($str)
)
),
'post_type' => 'product',
'orderby' => 'title,'
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
echo "<ul>";
while ($products - > have_posts()) {
    $products - > the_post();

    $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($product_category - > term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
    $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($cat_thumb_id);
    $term_link = get_term_link($product_category, 'product_cat');

    echo '<a href="'.$term_link.
    '"><img src="'.$cat_thumb_url.
    '"/></a>';
    echo '<h4><a class="'.$product_category - > slug.
    '" href="'.get_term_link($product_category).
    '">'.$product_category - > name.
    '</a></h4>';
    /*  echo '<h1><a class="' . $product_category->slug . '" href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h1>';*/
    ? >
    <!-- <li>
    < a href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
        <?php the_title(); ?> < /a> < /li>-->
    <?php
                                                            }
                                                            echo "</ul>";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ?>
```

If you guys have better ideas please post it here so that we can help each other Thanks.